# mitmproxy installation error

Tags: proxy, centos, egg, mitmproxy

I trying to install mitmproxy on centos 6.4 with python 2.6.6, I am getting below error when execute install command.

**#pip install mitmproxy**

```
Downloading/unpacking mitmproxy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mitmproxy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/mitmproxy/setup.py", line 19
        "netlib>=%s, <%s" % (version.MINORVERSION, version.NEXT_MINORVERSION),
                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/mitmproxy/setup.py", line 19

    "netlib>=%s, <%s" % (version.MINORVERSION, version.NEXT_MINORVERSION),

                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/mitmproxy
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Quick testing would indicate that that is a python 2.7.x syntax. (At least it doesn't work on 2.4.3 and 2.6.6 for me and does on 2.7.8.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error seems to indicate that mitmproxy is not compatible with python 2.6.x. I assume that syntax is new for 2.7.x or something like that.

That line doesn't work for me in 2.4.3 or 2.6.6 but does in 2.7.8.